# Unable to execute test

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

Any one got any ideas on whats going on. Visual Studio does not execute my tests, the test runner just sits there. 
See image below where i created a new project, a new test project with a single test.

[image: Screen shoot of test run]

Comment: So what happens? Just nothing happens, and a test is always in pending state?

Comment: Just pending. Im also unable to cancel test run.

Comment: If you will empty test method's body, will the same issue occur?

Comment: Same thing with empty test. I noticed that I can still use the ReSharper test runner. I will use that one going forward.

Comment: try to disable unit testing in ReSharper? What version of ReSh do you use?

Comment: What do your *active* test settings look like?

(You can check which are active via Test / Select Active Test Settings)